# Apache Spark bucketed table not scalable in time partitioned table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, bucket

I am trying to utilize Spark Bucketing on a key-value table that is frequently joined on the `key` column by batch applications. The table is partitioned by `timestamp` column, and new data arrives periodically and added in a new `timestamp` partition. Nothing new here.

I thought it was ideal use case for Spark bucketing, but some limitations seem to be fatal when the table is incremental:

1. Incremental table forces multiple files per bucket, forcing Spark to sort every bucket upon join even though every  file is sorted locally. Some Jira's suggest that this is a conscious design choice, not going to change any time soon. This is quite understood, too, as there could be thousands of locally sorted files in each bucket,  and iterating concurrently over so many files does not seem a good idea, either.
   Bottom line is, *sorting* cannot be avoided.
2. Upon map side join, every bucket is handled by a single Task. When the table is incremented, every such Task would consume more and more data as more partitions  (increments) are included in the join. Empirically, this ultimately failed on OOM regardless to the configured memory settings. To my understanding, even if the failures can be avoided, this design does not scale at all. It imposes an impossible trade-off when deciding on the number of buckets - aiming for a long term table results in lots of small files during every increment.

This gives the immediate impression that bucketing **should not be used** with incremental tables.  I wonder if anyone has a better opinion on that, or maybe I am missing some basics here.

Comment: Big data in one go is different to incremental data. JIRA thing is correct. So, there you have it... Title is incorrect, in your context there is an issue.

Comment: changed the title